# can calling pythons urllib2.info() cause an exception?

Tags: python, exception, urllib2

I'm getting a couple of exceptions popping up from time to time but can't think of the cause.

Here's a snippet:

```
    try:
        r = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        if hasattr(e, 'code'):
            # unauthorized
            print('UA: %s' % url)
        elif hasattr(e, 'reason'):
            print('TO: %s' % url)
            # timeout
    else:
        i = r.info()

        try:
            server = i['server']
        except:
            pass
        else:
            if not 'authenticate' in server:
                print('NA: %s' % url)
```

I'm thinking perhaps that r.info() is causing an exception but not sure why it would as the r = urllib2.urlopen(url) is covered with the try.

The errors are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\anthony\Scripts\checker.py", line 35, in run
    r = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1207, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1180, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1030, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 407, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 371, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
BadStatusLine: ''
```

and

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1207, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1180, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1030, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 407, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 447, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I've read a bit of information on the [Errno 10054] but have no idea how to prevent it.

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm thinking perhaps that r.info() is causing an exception but not
>   sure why it would as the r = urllib2.urlopen(url) is covered with the
>   try.

Nope.  The first exception has nothing to do with `r.info()` - exception is raised on `urllib2.urlopen(url)`, as you may see in the traceback.

`BadStatusLine` exception is defined in `httplib` and your `except urllib2.URLError` simply doesn't catch it.  You should probably improve your exception handling logic like:

```
except (httplib.HTTPException, urllib2.URLError) as err:
    ...
```

Comment: Great I'll have a play around with that and report back. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm still getting an [Errno 10054], is there anyway to capture that?

Comment: @cookertron Debug-debug-debug.  Look at the type and properties of exception object raised within this error, catch it too.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Having had a rather tedious debugging session without luck I installed httplib2 and this has solved the problem. In fact my script has become a lot simpler :)